# How to iterate through an array of objects in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I have this array right here and I need to get the "id" of each object

```
[{ id: 1, points: 60 }, { id: 2, points: 20 }, { id: 3, points: 95 }, { id: 4, points: 75 }]
        customers = [{ id: 1, points: 90 }, { id: 2, points: 20 }, { id: 3, points: 70 }, { id: 4, points: 40 }, { id: 5, points: 60 }, { id: 6, points: 10}]
```

I know how to go through the whole array with

```
@scores.each_with_index{ |score, index| }
```

However, I haven't found a way to get the objects's points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the following.

```
customers = [
  { id: 1, points: 90 }, { id: 2, points: 20 },
  { id: 3, points: 70 }, { id: 4, points: 40 },
  { id: 5, points: 60 }, { id: 6, points: 10}
]
```

```
h = customers.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  id, points = g.values_at(:id, :points)
  h[id] = points
end
  #=> {1=>90, 2=>20, 3=>70, 4=>40, 5=>60, 6=>10}
```

This allows you to easily extract information of interest, such as the following.

```
h.keys
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
h.values
  #=> [90, 20, 70, 40, 60, 10] 
h[2]
  #=> 20
h.key?(5)
  #=> true 
h.key?(7)
  #=> false 
h.value?(70)
  #=> true 
h.value?(30)
  #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

What you called `score` is actually an hash like `{ id: 1, points: 60 }` and I'm going to call it `item`

So, let's try

```
@scores.each_with_index do |item, index|
  puts "#{index + 1}: id #{item[:id]}, points #{item[:points]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, I have this array right here and I need to get the id of each object

In order to transform each element of a collection, you can use [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (or in this case more precisely [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map)):

```ruby
customers.map { _1[:id] }
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Jörg neglected to mention that [numbered block parameters](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.7.html#numbered-block-parameters) was introduced in Ruby v2.7. I suppose beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but to me that looks like it was whupped with an ugly stick. (Credit to [Bo Diddley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5jHLJce1Go&app=desktop) (at 2:51).)

Answer (score 1):

This given construct is an array of objects so we need to individually iterate through each element and print out the value present in the objects. The following code shows how we can do it:

```rb
customers.each{|obj| p obj[:id].to_s+" "+ obj[:points].to_s }
```

Here we iterate through each element and print out individual entities of the hash using the `obj[:id]`/`obj[:points]` (`obj` being each individual object here.)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
customers.map(&:to_proc).map{ |p| [:id, :points].map(&p) }
=> [[1, 90], [2, 20], [3, 70], [4, 40], [5, 60], [6, 10]]
```